# Webmatrix error when creating new site from folder "MACHINE/REDIRECTION"

Tags: windows, configuration, webmatrix, iis-express

I'm experiencing an error when creating a new site from a folder with Webmatrix.
I've used it for months now and i never had a problem with it, but yesterday when i went for create a new site i got this error with no other explanation:

```
ERROR

Cannot find configuration file 'MACHINE/REDIRECTION'.
```

I actually have no idea what caused it and what it is about, i tried looking in the configuration file of IIS Express installed with it but couldn't find anything related to it, even searching with google gave me no useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems redirection.config file that is supposed to be present in the %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\ folder is either doesn't exist or it is corrupted. You have two options.

**Option-1:**

1.Copy redirection.config file from %programfiles%\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer (or %programfiles(x86)\iis express\config\templates\personalwebserver) to %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\

2.Restart webmatrix

**Option-2:**

1.Rename iisexpress folder located in  %userprofile%\documents\

2.Restart WebMatrix

Note: If you follow option-2 steps you may not see websites that were created recently.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, sadly i don't know why it seems our network configuration makes necessary to do it every morning when i log in :( ( i also had to install webmatrix 2 beta since webmatrix now refuses to reinstall, giving an error when trying to install the Sql part :\ )